# JQuery trigger hover won't work with :not(:hover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-hover, mouseenter

I have a case very similar to this one: https://codepen.io/ianfarb/pen/EJunm

I'm trying to use jquery mouseenter to trigger a hover on the first image which has Id one.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('#one').trigger('mouseenter');
}, 2500)
```

However this doesn't appear to work, neither in my code nor in the one in the link above, as :not(:hover) style appears to always be applied. I've also tried with $().offset() to trigger redraw but that won't work either.

Comment: May not be relevant but `#1` is an invalid ID in CSS

Comment: Generally starting an `id` with a number might be a problem.

Comment: Id really does not matter in the problem I'm facing, it was just an example

Comment: jQuery's `trigger()` triggers event handlers, not styles.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How could I trigger the first element to be hovered programattically in that fiddle?

Comment: I mean that jQuery's `trigger()` will trigger an event bound with javascript, if **will not** trigger styles set with CSS.

Comment: I see... how could I trick it to trigger those?

Comment: Use a regular class instead of the pseudoclass `:hover` and add the class with javascript

Comment: There are so many easier ways to do this..JQuery animate on hover with $(this), you can also add :hover to the css if you're dealing with ID's (although this would be cumbersom). You can also add a class on hover to $(this) with a transition duration.

Comment: Allright, post an answer then please so I can check it and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I don't want to use javascript animation for performance considerations A.Sharma. Adding hover with jquery won't do either.

Comment: Do you want the hover effect to start 2.5s after the mouseenter? And is this triggered by the user or not?

Comment: Hover is more like a state not an event, so you can't bind or trigger an event to it. You may use `$.fn.hover` or `$('...').on('mouseenter', function ....)` and add the proper classes with the hover effects to the element if you really want to trigger it from javascript. Otherwise I recommend using pure css

Comment: @RicardoRuiz - value of timeout doesn't matter, I thought it may be good to it finish rendering. It is not triggered by user.

Comment: First I thought it was caused by the fact that my :hover and :not(:hover) add transitions...

Comment: @AlexC - You can't trigger `:hover`, and you can't add it either, as javascript doesn't have access to pseudoclasses like `:hover`, `:before` etc. You could probably do something like `#test.hovered, #test:hover { styles }` where you add a regular class to the same style, as regular classes can be manipulated by javascript.

Comment: @adeneo, Yes, I understood that, that's why I asked you to post a propper answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Is something like this what you want? [**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/kt0vp77L/) Wait 2.5s to see the effect.

Comment: @RicardoRuiz not exactly, because that way hover won't work when done by the user anymore :)

Comment: It all depends in what you want, be more specific, I think I can make it work. Check this: [**JSFiddle demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/7ykg4gp4/) Here the animation has no seconds set for you to change it if you want to. If you don't really want an animation there's another approach.

Comment: @RicardoRuiz - here's the more specific actual case: https://jsfiddle.net/alexc1/kbg9uzad/ - got 4 images which widen when hovered. When loading I just want the first one to be hovered. However after I hover another the new one should widen and the first one ('hovered' on load) to go back to original width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class to apply the hover styles (using `opacity` for example)

```
.image {
  opacity: .5;
}

.image:hover,
.image.is-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

and then add it in your timeout (and make sure to cleanup the class on real hovers)

```
jQuery(function($) {
  function enter() {
    $(this).addClass('is-hover').siblings().removeClass('is-hover');
  }

  function leave() {
    $(this).removeClass('is-hover');
  }

  $('.image').hover(enter, leave);

  setTimeout(function() {
    enter.call($('.image:first-child'));
  }, 2500);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for